# Is $L^{4}\left(X,\nu\right)$ contained in $L^{4}\left(X,\mu\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

> Let $\mu$   and $\nu$   be positive measures in
>   $\left(X,\mathrm{\mathcal{M}}\right)$  . Assume that
>   $\mu\left(E\right)\leq\nu\left(E\right)\forall E\in\mathcal{M}$  . Is
>   $L^{4}\left(X,\nu\right)$   contained in $L^{4}\left(X,\mu\right)$  ?

I try to let $f\in L^{4}\left(X,\nu\right)$, I show that $f\in L^{4}\left(X,\mu\right)$. Since $f\in L^{4}\left(X,\nu\right)$, we have $\int_{E}\left|f\right|^{4}d\nu<\infty$. And $\int_{E}\left|f\right|^{4}d\mu\leq\int_{E}\left|f\right|^{4}d\nu<\infty
 $ (since $\mu\left(E\right)\leq\nu\left(E\right)\forall E\in\mathcal{M}$). That means $f\in L^{4}\left(X,\mu\right)$, so we are done.

Is my proof exact?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's exact. Maybe the inequality 
$$\int_E g\mathrm d\mu\leqslant \int_E g\mathrm d\nu$$ 
for $g$ non-negative has to be justified going back to simple functions with non-negative coefficients.

Comment: +1 vote: Thank you very much :)

Comment: You are welcome.